# ISSUE IN SEARCH FUNCTIONALITY

Tags: lightning

On enter keypress, a spinner should rotate  showing the search results.How to do it in lightning?Any suggestions regarding it would be thankful

search helper code

```
SearchHelper: function(component, event,searchKeyWord) {

    var action = component.get("c.getAccounts");
    action.setParams({
        'searchKeyWord': searchKeyWord
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var storeResponse = response.getReturnValue();
            // if storeResponse size is 0 ,display no record found message on screen.
            if (storeResponse.length == 0) {
                component.set("v.infoMessage", true);
            } else {
                component.set("v.infoMessage", false);
            }
            // set numberOfRecord attribute value with length of return value from server
            component.set("v.TotalNumberOfRecord", storeResponse.length);
            // set searchResult list with return value from server.
            component.set("v.allData", storeResponse);
        }
```

Comment: check it updated answer

Comment: cmp code im using as below

<div aura:id="lookupField" class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                <lightning:icon class="slds-input__icon slds-show-medium" iconName="utility:search" size="x-small" alternativeText="search"/>
                <lightning:input class="slds-size_1-of-5" name="input7" aura:id="accountSearch" onchange="{!c.keyPressController}" value="" placeholder="search this list.."/>

Comment: controller code 

keyPressController : function(component, event, helper) {
        
        var getInputkeyWord =  component.find('accountSearch').get('v.value');    
        if (getInputkeyWord == '' || getInputkeyWord == null) {
            
            
        } else {              
            helper.SearchHelper(component,event,getInputkeyWord);
        }
    },

Comment: helper.SearchHelper is there in that please below line of code:component.find("Id_spinner").set("v.class" , 'slds-show');
   //Decide when to hide it,may be based on response  write below line of code

    component.find("Id_spinner").set("v.class" , 'slds-hide')

Comment: im also using searchhelper code in js, but where am i doing wrong in my code can you pls help

Comment: i havenot seen completed code: in searchhelpercode just place my logic.

Comment: i have posted my search helper code, can you please check where am i doing wrong?

Comment: have you checked my code.please check it you have answer there only...you need to identify it

Comment: some problem in your code.i updated it... lightning spinner will surely work..

Comment: i just explain about spinner..if you have any other issue..please open new question..if its related spinner surely my  code will work

Comment: If it ressolves your issue.please make it as best answer..itshelpfull for other people looking for similar answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In aura component write below line of code:

> component side

```
  <lightning:spinner variant="brand" size="large" aura:id="Id_spinner" class="slds-hide" />
```

whenever we click on search call method in js:

> Javascript:

```
     SearchHelper: function(component, event) {
    component.find("Id_spinner").set("v.class" , 'slds-show');
   //Decide when to hide it,may be based on response  write below line of code

    component.find("Id_spinner").set("v.class" , 'slds-hide');
```

Let me Answer based on your code (check basic skelton)

```
    SearchHelper: function(component, event,searchKeyWord) {
      component.find("Id_spinner").set("v.class" , 'slds-show');
       action.setParams({
    'searchKeyWord': searchKeyWord
       });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    var state = response.getState();
    if (state === "SUCCESS") {
    //After getting result hidding spinner
   component.find("Id_spinner").set("v.class" , 'slds-hide');
  var storeResponse = response.getReturnValue();
        // if storeResponse size is 0 ,display no record found message on screen.
        if (storeResponse!=null && storeResponse.length>0) {
        component.set("v.TotalNumberOfRecord", storeResponse.length);

            component.set("v.allData", storeResponse);
            component.set("v.infoMessage", false);

        } else {
             component.set("v.infoMessage", true);
        }
```